# Experience slow down when using importlib.machinery instead of using setuptools to install .so file and then import it

Tags: python, setuptools, pybind11, python-importlib

I'm having some trouble to understand what's happening here.
(Case 1) Originally, I installed my pybind11 generated .so file with setuptools and then do the normal import in python.
(Case 2) Now, I directly point importlib to the .so file location and create the module on the fly.
However, when using the module after all the setups are done, Case 1 runs much faster than Case 2.
The way I did in Case 2 is:

```
import importlib
modname, filename = 'pacakge',"path/to/package.so"
loader = importlib.machinery.ExtensionFileLoader(modname, filename)
spec = importlib.machinery.ModuleSpec(
    name = modname,
    loader = loader,
    origin = filename,
)
module_going_to_use = loader.create_module(spec)

# do something with module_going_to_use 
# (and this part is much slower than Case 1).
```

Any suggestions on what may cause this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My guess is that there is a setup step that the second case puts off until the module is actually used.  A key test of this is to try to use `module_going_to_use` twice in the same scope.  If you do the same thing that you're doing with `module_going_to_use` a second time, does that second time run more quickly?  If it does, then you have your answer.  If that's the case, then you have a good reason to do things the other way to not incur that setup cost every time your code runs.

Comment: I'm guessing in case 1, some work is done at install time to make importing the module at runtime faster. In case 2, your code is forced to read and process the `.so` from scratch at runtime. My bet is the best choice for you is to use case 1.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But, I just timed the experiment you said, running two times don't seem to have an effect. :(